# SwiftUI Size Struct by .frame modifier

Tags: swift, swiftui

Hello I got a Custom Button Struct which has an Image and a Text and also a Style for that Button, which is added at the end of the Struct. My Question is: Is there any way I can use the .frame(width: , height: ) and .frame(minWidth: maxWidth) modifier, without passing a variable to the struct which then passes it to the button style?

CustomButton:

```
struct CustomButtonWithImage: View {
let title: String
let image: String
let action: () -> Void

var body: some View {
    Button(action: action) {
        HStack {
            Image(image)
                .resizable()
                .renderingMode(.template)
                .frame(maxWidth: imageSize.width, maxHeight: imageSize.height)
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            Text(title)
                .font(.system(size: fontSize))
                .bold()
                .minimumScaleFactor(0.8)
                .lineLimit(1)
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, horizontalPadding)
    }
    .buttonStyle(CustomButtonStyle(size: buttonSize)) // <- Button Style
    .accentColor(Color.white)
}
```

}

```
struct CustomButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {

func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
    configuration
        .label
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        .accentColor(Color.white)
        .background(Color("CustomButtonColor"))
}
```

}

Basically I just want to Do this:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        CustomButton(text: "hello": image("someImage.png") { print("hello") }
            // Is there a way to set this without passing the struct a var or let?
            // I can set this but this wont make the button bigger, because the label in the button style wont change size with this
            .frame(width: 40, height: 50)
            .frame(maxWidth: ..., maxHeight: ...)
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove hardcoded frame and add max allowed, so it will consume available space shrank only by other views layout. Also you can use only one, either `maxWidth` or `maxHeight` restriction if needed.

```swift
CustomButton(text: "hello": image("someImage.png") { print("hello") }
//    .frame(width: 40, height: 50)    // remove hardcode
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)  // << max allowed
```

Comment: Thanks I had to put .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity) in the HStack of the CustomButton. Then i could change the frame easily.